# Tiled and MonoGame.Extended - How to handle collisions?

Tags: c#, collision-detection, monogame, tiled

I use Tiled to edit my maps, and I would like to set-up a collision system with my game.

I tried to set properties on some tiles of the tilesets I use, but the problem is that I can't access them from MonoGame.Extended, actually the library doesn't seem to be designed for this purpose, and I don't understand why.

i.e. when I look in the `TiledMapTile` class there is no property at all, certainly there are `TiledMapTilesetTile` objects from the `TiledMapTileset` class that contains properties, but how can I get this object from a position? What I want is something like this:

```cs
bool isCollisionTile = tiledMap.GetTile(x, y).Properties["IsCollisionTile"];
```

I'm also open to other approaches to handle collisions, either by using another C# Tiled support library for MonoGame/XNA, or by changing my approach of this problem, and find a completely different solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always export the tile map you use to JSON if you like. See [JSON-map-format](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/stable/reference/json-map-format/).

> Tiled can export maps as JSON files. To do so, simply select “File >
>   Export As” and select the JSON file type. You can export json from the
>   command line with the --export-map option.

Load your JSON in monogame and access the properties from there.

You can get the tile that the player is on using the ff:

```
int playerPosX = 0;
int playerPosY = 0;
int tileWidth = 32;

// TiledMap map
TiledMapTileLayer layer = map.GetLayer<TiledMapTileLayer>("Collision");
TiledMapTile? tile = null;

ushort x = (ushort)(playerPosX / tileWidth);
ushort y = (ushort)(playerPosY / tileWidth);

// Get tile based on player position
layer.TryGetTile(x, y, out tile);

if (tile.HasValue)
{
    // collided!
    // you can also compute the tile's position using the X, Y and tileWidth if needed.
}
```

Comment: Okay I understood! I'm going to use a layer for collisions and everything will be easier.